# Why do I need a const lambda when calling std::partition

Tags: c++, reference, stl, reference-binding

I have this function which uses std::partition to split a container into two based on a predicate.

```
template<class Container, class Predicate>
void split_partition(Container& src, Container& dest, Predicate p)
{

    auto ends = std::partition_copy(
        std::make_move_iterator( src.begin() ), std::make_move_iterator( src.end() ),
        src.begin(), std::back_inserter(dest), p
    ); 

    src.erase(ends.first, src.end());

}
```

I tried calling it with

```
split_partition(a, b, [](auto& t) {return t.i > 4; });
```

but it didn't even compile, now if use **const** it does work.

```
split_partition(a, b, [](const auto& t) {return t.i > 4; });
```

Why is that?

Edit:

```
std::vector<Thing> a = { {0, "foo"}, {1, "bar"}, {5, "what"}, {8, "yo"}, {2, ""} };
std::vector<Thing> b;
```

Comment: Because you're not allowed to fiddle and modify this stuff? Can't think of a better way to ensure that the closure won't do something stupid.

Comment: Looks like `a` is `const` at the call site.

Comment: Showing the definitions of `a` and `b` would make it easier for folks to see what's happening.

Comment: Note, however, that the behavior of the program is undefined if either of the output ranges in the call to [`std::partition_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy) overlaps the input range. The code in the question passes the beginning of the input range as the location for the first output range; that won't fly.

Comment: @PeteBecker Just simple containers, I added the definition.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's not the problem. I'm calling it the right way, the src.begin() in the 3rd parameters is for the partition elements that satisfy the lamda , it's not "overlapping" anything

Comment: @Slava -- instead of trickling out information (your question doesn't define `Thing`) post real code. Post the smallest example you can come up with that shows the problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker do I need to?  it's just a struct with an int and a std::string

Comment: @slava Yes you do.

Comment: @Slava -- you're asking people to do you a favor; you should make it as easy as possible to copy your code, paste it into a local file, and compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `std::partition` with a moved-from range:

```cpp
std::make_move_iterator( src.begin() ), std::make_move_iterator( src.end() )
```

This means that the lambda you have is going to be invoked with some `Object&&` or `const Object&&`. `const auto&` can bind to it in either case.
`const auto&` is universal in the sense that it can bind to any value category (lvalue, xvalue, prvalue).

For example:

```cpp
#include <utility>

// Calls to opaque copy constructor should be visible in ASM.
// This would let us spot accidental copies/moves, if they took place.
struct S { S(const S&); };

void test(const S x, S y) {
    const auto& r0 = x;            // bind to lvalue const S
    const auto& r1 = std::move(x); // bind to xvalue const S
    const auto& r2 = y;            // bind to lvalue S
    const auto& r3 = std::move(y); // bind to xvalue S
}
```

This code compiles to

```
test(S, S):
        ret
```

This means that no constructor of `S` was called, `const&` simply binds to anything.
Since you're using `std::move_iterator` (which is pointless for the purpose of comparison), your case is either `r1` or `r3`.

`auto&` isn't quite so powerful: a non-const lvalue reference cannot bind to a const xvalue. This would be `r3`, and that's the case you're running into.

> Otherwise [if the reference isn't bound to an lvalue of the same/to a compatible type], if the reference is an lvalue reference to a type that is **not const-qualified or is volatile-qualified**, the program is ill-formed.

- [[dcl.init.ref] p5.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.2)

#### Solution

Just accept `const auto&` in your lambda. It's more correct since you're just comparing elements without modifying them anyway.

Comment: hey, i was thinking about this again the other day, const auto&& works too in this case right?

Comment: @Slava I'm pretty sure I've tested that and it would work too, but it would be a `const` rvalue reference which is somewhat contradictory since it's immutable, but also implies that something can be moved from. It wouldn't be a `const` forwarding reference. In general, const rvalue references are something that shouldn't occur outside of weird cases in generic code.

Comment: yeah i thought about that, but since you said 'universal' i immeditely thoughta about `const auto&&`, but it seems that `const auto&` is also universal